# How can I pass socket as an argument do ButtonClick handler function?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need to pass my Socket variable to function that handles clicking of a button. It's a Tic-Tac-Toe game that I'm trying to make that it sends the outcome of the game to server. In my ButtonClick() (which is used for each of 9 cells), I have a function that checks if someone won, and if yes it sould send the outcome to the server.

I've tried starting the client every win win the check fynction but i just freezes the program and does nothing. I've come up an Idea that i can start the client in the constructor and then in my check function only send the info about winner. So the problem emerges, and I can't pass my socket through the event handler function because it only accepts two arguments.

These are button definitions:

```xml
<Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Button0_0" Click="ButtonClick" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Button1_0" Click="ButtonClick" />
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Button2_0" Click="ButtonClick" />
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Button0_1" Click="ButtonClick" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Button1_1" Click="ButtonClick" />
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="Button2_1" Click="ButtonClick" />
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="Button0_2" Click="ButtonClick" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="Button1_2" Click="ButtonClick" />
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="Button2_2" Click="ButtonClick" />
```

This is my button handler:

```cs
 private void ButtonClick(object sender1, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mGameEnded) {
                NewGame();
                return;
            }
            //operations
            CheckWinner();
        }
```

And here is the necessary part of my check funtion:

```cs
 private void CheckWinner()
        {
            //checking operations

            if (mGameEnded)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(winner, "Who won?");

                // Encode the data string into a byte array.    
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(winner);

                // Send the data through the socket.    
                sender.Send(msg);

            }

        }
```

As you can see, I'd need to pass the socket through the ButtonClick() to the CheckWinner() to use the SendToServer() function.

Comment: Ok, i kinda did it, just need to change something in server now. So I've uset static variables to make socket and then used them to send messages to server.

Comment: There's no point in making socket a static variable. It can be an instance variable. All you need to be able to do is get at it from the click handler and a private instance variable will work fine for that.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't best practice, but...

Add another private method socketSend to your window.

That takes parameters like the msg.

That can instantiate a sockkect, send the msg and close the connection.

Similar to ExecuteClient in this:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-c-sharp/

Since all your methods are private members of the window, you could just make your socket another private member and ButtonClick could reference it.

If you're learning wpf for professional use you might be wondering about best practice.

Look into MVVM and break out your functionality into separate classes. Then look into dependency injection. All that is some time down the road if you're a beginner though.